What if I found out that I missed adding some citations to my thesis after the final submission
What if I missed adding some citations to the my thesis after the final submission to the graduate editorial office? Still few days before graduation

Ask your supervisor! Chances are it depends on local rules whether you can (or even should) do anything about this, and we can't tell you.

What if the editorial office has strict rules concerning the final submission

Again your supervisor will know how to deal with the rules. But this sounds like a clerical error not a didn't-do-the-work error, so I'd hope they'd be sympathetic.

In academia, it's very common to learn about papers related to your research after you've written your literature review, after submitting, or even after publishing. It's expected. No literature review can contain every single bit of connected literature. Normally, when you submit a paper to a journal, the referee has a chance to point you to relevant literature you may have missed. Giving talks at conferences is another way to get this feedback. But even with all that, sometimes you will realize years after publishing, that your literature review was incomplete.
It's great that you want to improve your thesis even at the last minute. If that's allowed, then by all means add to the bibliography. But it's also fine to fix this up in the version of the thesis that you submit for publication (e.g., in math, you might turn the thesis into two or three papers, and their literature review can be more thorough than the one in the thesis).
Remember that no one expects the thesis to be perfect. The only question is whether it's above the bar and earns you the degree. Almost no one ever goes back to read your actual thesis. They read the papers you published based on your thesis.
Now, if "missed adding some citations" is code for "plagiarized" then my answer changes entirely. It's important to give credit where it is due, if you got an idea from somewhere else, or quoted something else but failed to cite it or use quotation marks. In cases like that, you'd want to try hard to fix the thesis and explain the situation to your advisor and committee, so they could accurately assess the thesis and so that the library doesn't end up microfilming and keeping on file a work created using plagiarism. But I doubt you're in that situation.
